# Joining Census Data

Tags: arcgis-10.0, data, census

I have collected census data for a county in Pennsylvania.  Data varies from 1999-2010.  For my data before 2010, a significant number of blocks do not match up (image below) when I join the data (based on GEOID).

I have joined to 1990, 2000 and 2010 census block groups.  There are roughly the same number of block groups, but the GEOID's are always off for maybe 30% of the block groups.[image]

I feel like i'm missing something here...  Anyone had trouble with this before?

So I'm offering a bounty now.  Basically I just need to be able to join this data with the shapefile block groups from any year...  But my guess is that they would best align with 2000.

Comment: Typically the census released crosswalk files of the changes, but in a quick search I was not able to find any for blocks. [This website](http://www.psc.isr.umich.edu/dis/census/crosswalk.html) has them for larger geographies.

Comment: True, but I tried to join my data to past census block group shapefiles as well, and the result is the same, albeit in a slightly different way....  If there were changes between say 2000 and 2010, wouldn't my 2000 data still match up with 2000 shapefiles?  It doesn't though...

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your saying. If your 2000 census data does not match up to 2000 census geographies then you have problems with GEOID's in one of your data files, not with the geography (or changes in the geography). This could be anything, such as you are mistaken as to what the files are, or some errors in the data occurred somewhere. You haven't given enough information to really help besides point to the crosswalk files.

Comment: Ok.  This is the meta data included with the data download...       P052
HOUSEHOLD INCOME IN 1999 [17]

Universe: Households

NOTE: Data based on a sample except in P3, P4, H3, and H4. For
information on confidentiality protection, sampling error,
nonsampling error, definitions, and count corrections see
http://factfinder.census.gov/home/en/datanotes/expsf3.htm.

Comment: I think you are right that there is an error somewhere.  In this case the data is from 1999.  Is there blockgroup information at less than census intervals (I was trying 1990, 2000 and 2010 block group shapefiles)?  say from 1998 or 1999?

Comment: No (there are no intermediate census geographies that I am aware of), typically what is done is assign data based on a particular decennial census geography. It seems likely the data in 1999 was using 1990 census geographies. Hopefully the data comes with enough independent meta-data to figure these things out without resorting to just matching the numbers, but I realize circumstances aren't always so kind!

Comment: In case it's useful, here are links to the Census Block Relationship files:  2000 - http://www.census.gov/geo/www/relate/rel_blk.html   2010 - http://www.census.gov/geo/www/2010census/rel_blk.html

Comment: The P052 table should be directly from the 2000 Census -- that particular data is lagged by a year -- so I'm not sure why your data won't match with those blocks. Did you obtain both the data and the shapefiles directly from the Census Bureau?

Comment: p052 from american fact finder.  and blockgroup shapefile from http://www.census.gov/geo/www/cob/bg2000.html

Comment: My workflow, is to take the .csv from american factfinder, cut down the full GEOID in excel =right/left(column, # of charters) so that it matches with the shapefiles GEOID.  Then bring into arcgis and join...

Comment: and now for 2010 they are pre-joined! https://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-data.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would check that you have downloaded the correct census files. I've spent many wasted days trying to figure out why I could not make an obvious join, only to discover that 2010 census files per state and per county sometimes have different codes. (I know this sounds strange but it is true).

Secondly, in the pre-2010 census, you should check how the LOCRECGNO number is constructed. There is a 6 digit code in there, and ArcGIS removes the prefix 00. So `004349` is `4349` Sometimes you need to pad the column of numbers so that the string is 6 characters long. This is only true when you try to construct the LOCRECGNO number from it's constituent parts.  Again, it is an incredibly basic step that should not be necessary but I have also found this problem very hard to spot as some joins work (and others do not).

I found this [site](http://proximityone.com/cen2010_plfile.htm) had a useful description of census fields. I joined all blockgroups in the US to the tabular data using census data from [here](http://www.census.gov/geo/www/tiger/tgrshp2010/tgrshp2010.html) and [here](ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2010BLKPOPHU/).

Comment: Good advice.  I am joining based on GEOID (which i assume is equal to LOCRECGNO).  The numbers all have the same digits, but about half are off - and randomly, for each join I have tried using 2010, 2000, and 1990 shapefiles...

Comment: I'm working from memory here, but I don't believe the GEOID had the same 4/6 character issue as the entire GEOID is included if you grab the correct shapefile.

Comment: Yeah they vary in length, but you can cut them down to match.  I've done this successfully with 2010 data.  My problem is only with census data prior to 2010.  I must use 2000 data as 2010 data for many variables has yet to be released at the block group level.

Comment: Just solved it.  I knew I was missing something...  You were right, arc was deleting those zeros and I had to *100 to get them back in.